# Concatenate a date and time value

Tags: javascript, datetime

i need to concatenate a date value and a time value to make one value representing a datetime in javascript.

thanks,
daniel

Comment: What format or object type is the original date and time value?

Comment: What format are the date and time value currently in, and what is your desired output format?  Javascript's native Date() object *is* a datetime, you could instantiate on using the parameter info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date .  You can use a third-party library like http://www.datejs.com/ to make displaying it in a human-readable format simpler.

Comment: both values (date and time) are in string format. the desired output is (month-day-year hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "date" is the date string and "time" is the time string:

```
// create Date object from valid string inputs
var datetime = new Date(date+' '+time);

// format the output
var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
var day = datetime.getDate();
var year = datetime.getFullYear();

var hour = this.getHours();
if (hour < 10)
    hour = "0"+hour;

var min = this.getMinutes();
if (min < 10)
    min = "0"+min;

var sec = this.getSeconds();
if (sec < 10)
    sec = "0"+sec;

// put it all togeter
var dateTimeString = month+'/'+day+'/'+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec;
```

Comment: 1. The javascript date object will do some funny things when parsing.  For example, 11:70 will be interpreted as 12:10.
2. The resulting datetime will be in the browser's timezone
3. If the input is invalid, isNaN(datetime.getTime()) == true

Comment: True on all points.

However, the OP made no mention of validating the inputs, so the assumption is that the date and time values collected are valid string representations of dates and times.

Comment: don't worry, validation is never a developers concern... it's the user's fault if he supplies invalid data...

Answer (score 11):

Working with strings is fun and all, but let's suppose you have two datetimes and don't like relying on strings.

```
function combineDateWithTime(d, t)
{
   return new Date(
    d.getFullYear(),
    d.getMonth(),
    d.getDate(),
    t.getHours(),
    t.getMinutes(),
    t.getSeconds(),
    t.getMilliseconds()
    );
}
```

Test:

```
var taxDay = new Date(2016, 3, 15); // months are 0-indexed but years and dates aren't.
var clockout = new Date(0001, 0, 1, 17);
var timeToDoTaxes = combineDateWithTime(taxDay, clockout);
// yields: Fri Apr 15 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Not sure why the service I was consuming separates them to begin with.... Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I could not make the accepted answer work so used moment.js

```
date = moment(selected_date + ' ' + selected_time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

  date._i   "11-06-2014 13:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the original date and time value there are some different ways to approach this.

A Date object (which has both date and time) may be created in a number of ways.

```
birthday = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
birthday = new Date(1995,11,17);
birthday = new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

If the original date and time also is objects of type Date, you may use getHours(), getMinutes(), and so on to extract the desired values.

For more information, see Mozilla Developer Center for the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) object.

If you provide more detailed information in your question I may edit the answer to be more specific.

Comment: sorry for the insufficient info. I am using a datapicker to allow the user to pick a date that is represented as: exp: 1/1/2009. The time value is simply a textbox that allows the user to enter a time in this format: hh:mm.

Comment: @danielea: `1/1/2009` is ambiguous, is it `month-day-year`, or `day-month-year`?

Comment: it is (month-day-year). Additionally, the end results needs to be in the following format: (month-day-year hh:mm:ss) and then it needs to be URLEncoded