# How to combine values from a date and a time input to one date object?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to combine the values of a time and a date input into one date object.

```
    <div id="picker">
        Date: <input type="date" name="date" value="2099-08-01" id="date_"/>
        Time: <input type="time" name="time" value="20:00" id="time_"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        var d = document.getElementById("date_").valueAsDate;
        var t = document.getElementById("time_").valueAsDate
        //?
    </script>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: just concatenate according to the formate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate a date and time value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697728/concatenate-a-date-and-time-value)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// create Date object from valid string inputs
var datetime = new Date(date+' '+time);

// format the output
var month = datetime.getMonth()+1;
var day = datetime.getDate();
var year = datetime.getFullYear();

var hour = this.getHours();
if (hour < 10)
    hour = "0"+hour;

var min = this.getMinutes();
if (min < 10)
    min = "0"+min;

var sec = this.getSeconds();
if (sec < 10)
    sec = "0"+sec;

// put it all togeter
var dateTimeString = month+'/'+day+'/'+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec;
```

[Concatenate a date and time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697728/concatenate-a-date-and-time-value)